# Filling form with referrer cookie JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies

I am not very good with JS coding, what i am trying to do is to set cookie with JS and then retrieve it with code in specific field ID. Problem is I am generating form fields based on user geo-location and using Gravity forms, unfortunately gravity forms wont allow me to set class to input so i have to use two different IDs.

This is my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("input_2_7").value = getCookie("tir_referrer");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("input_3_7").value = getCookie("tir_referrer");
</script><code>
```

Now, when user loads website from certain country, he gets input field "2_7" and when other country is loaded the input is "3_7" where first num is form ID and second is form field ID.

The two JS scripts above put cookie in field 7, this works but the problem is when only one form is on site Chrome console outputs an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
at (index):740
```

Form filling work regardless and only script that is not needed fails, but i want to improve the code and only use one JS for this for both IDs, while heaving some error handling, hope someone can enlighten me on how to.

Regards, D

Answer (score 0):

Just check if getElementById returned an element reference (if it does not find the element, it will just return `null`), before you try to access properties such as `value`:

```
var input_2_7 = document.getElementById("input_2_7");
if(input_2_7) { 
  input_2_7.value = getCookie("tir_referrer");
}
```